# Why is "lens" not "len"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

In optics, why is "lens" not "len" used?

Why is "lens" used as a singular not plural?

Comment: http://www.focus.olsztyn.pl/en-grammar-nouns-uncountable-s.html

Answer (score 16):

Not every word in English that ends in *-s* is plural.

Consider:

gas
bus
canvas
news
atlas

The *why* is probably because the word *lens* was taken from the Latin word *lens,* which is also singular. See [Online Etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lens). The *Oxford English Dictionary* says the same.

Comment: Isn't News a plural of New? 
A Newspaper contains many articles of new things that happen.
"I have good news (many good new things)"
Like Sweets (pieces of candy) - a group of things is described by their main adjective in plural.

Comment: @DraxDomax agree, news is not a great example here and probably adds more confusion than clarity since it is formed out of a plural construction, even if it is often used grammatically as singular.

Comment: @BobH the weirdest thing is I don't think I wrote that. I am not interested in this question and I don't really know what an adjective is

Answer (score 6):

In optics, lens is a singular noun and its plural is "lenses". A noun that ends with " s" doesn't necessarily mean it's a plural.

Comment: Well, *len* exists in English as a [first name](http://www.behindthename.com/name/len) and as a [computer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Len_%28programming%29).